# How to render whole tree from within React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a higher-order component, and I'd like it to render out all of the composed component's children, and their children, all the way down the line.

When I call render(), though, it only renders the component's children, not their children's children.

How do I render it all the way down?

Here's some code:

```
export default ComposedComponent => {
  class HoC extends ComposedComponent {
    render() {
      console.log(super.render())
    }
  }

  return HoC
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call render manually. Render is automatically called upon initialisation, and every time the `props` and `state` change. And when render is called on an element, it is also called on all its child elements.

Additionally, don't use inheritance. React components extend `React.Component`, they never extend other components.

Comment: Hmmmmmmm

I'm doing some pretty intense sh\*t (basically making a better version of Radium that works with react-native), so I think this might be an exception to never calling render.

I'd like to render the entire tree of components and get *all* of their style properties and then process them, but render only goes one-level deep.

Comment: Render goes all the way down the tree, but the benefit of React is that it doesn't needlessly re-render things that have not changed.  If you're seeing that items are not re-rendering, it means that they should display the same thing so there was no need to render.  If for whatever reason you *need* them to render at specific times, then React is probably a bad choice, as you're actively going out of your way to undo the main thing that makes it special.